# Can't read/parse Riot API Match v5 results (Javascript/NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, riot-games-api

So i'm trying to use the https://americas.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/ get function and read values from the results. I can read it fine, but when I go to reference a field from it, i get this undefined issue, (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DIyo.png). When I try to do JSON.parse to it, I get this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOjok.png) even though when I copy and paste the json to json lint, it validates it all fine.

At this point I've tried every possible naming convention, validating the JSON, I've tried converting it to string to remove white spaces. Honestly I'm just a bit stumped as the other Riot API calls I've used have been working completely fine with no issue (match/v5/matches/by-puuid/ and summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/). Here is the code:

```
function getMatch(matchId,puId){

  const https = require('node:https');
 
  https.get('https://americas.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/'+matchId+'?api_key='+riotApiKey, (resp) => {
  
        resp.on('data', (d) => {        
          
          process.stdout.write(d.info.gameDuration);
          let matchResults = JSON.parse(d);
       
        });        
    });
  
}
```

Here is the response i get: https://pastebin.com/0f7waaAJ

Comment: Did you try to use the normal `fetch` rather than `https.get`?

Comment: @devnull69 I have not, that was my final hail Mary idea. Just very weird to me why my other https.get work fine except for this one where I'm now having issues

Comment: @devnull69 can confirm the Fetch works for it, had to install an older version of fetch cause I'm using replit but works perfectly. Still strange but probably just gonna use that